# JSON webservice using multiple databases

Tags: php, jquery, json, database, web-services

I had a web-service built using PHP in JSON format. The web service need to get the data from two different databases,

#### 1st DB with table posts1

id | firstnane | lastname | title | image

#### 2nd DB with table posts2

id | Experience | Designation | company | location

and here is my code

```
   <?php
$connection1=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",'json_data_db1');
$connection2=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",'json_data_db2');
// queries for 1st connection
$query  = "select firstname,lastname,title,url from posts where id='6'";
$sql=mysqli_query($connection1,$query) or die(mysql_error());

echo '{"posts": [';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
$firstname=$row['firstname'];
$lastname=$row['lastname'];
$title=$row['title'];
$url=$row['url'];
echo '{"firstname":"'.$firstname.'","lastname":"'.$lastname.'","title":"'.$title.'","image":"'.$url.'"},';
}
//echo ']}';
//echo '{"profession": [';

// queries for 2nd connection 
$query  = "select * from posts2 where id='6' limit 20";
$sql=mysqli_query($connection2,$query);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $exp=$row['exp'];
        $des=$row['des'];
        $company=$row['company'];
        $location=$ow['location'];
        echo '{"experience":"'.$exp.'","designation":"'.$des.'","company":"'.$company.'","location":"'.$location.'"},';     

    }

echo ']}';

mysqli_close($connection1);
mysqli_close($connection2);
?>
```

the json data which results is

> {
>     "posts": [
>       {
>         "firstname": "devika",
>         "lastname": "v",
>         "title": "Hyderabad",
>         "image": "Chrysanthemum.jpg"
>       },
>       {
>         "experience": "software engineer",
>         "designation": "Software Engineer",
>         "company": "Topnottch",
>         "location": ""
>       }, 
>       ]
>       }

and my code for parsing the JSON data is givenbelow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.getJSON("json_data.php",function(data)
{

$.each(data.posts, function(i,data)
{

var div_data =
"<div ><table width='500' border='1'><tr><tr><td>"+data.firstname+"</td><td>"+data.lastname+"</td><td>"+data.title+"</td><td><img src='images/"+data.image+"' width='40' height='40'></td><td>"+data.experience+"</td><td>"+data.designation+"</td><td>"+data.company+"</td><td>"+data.location+"</td></tr></table></div>";
$(div_data).appendTo("#data_area");

});
}
);
return false;
});
});
</script>
<div id="data_area"></div>
```

Its parsing the first-name,last-name,title and image.But its not parsing the experience,designation,company and location.can anyone please help me .

Comment: I suppose this gives you two tables. One filled with the info from the first db, and one with the info from the second db. This is how I read your code.

Comment: Yes. but its not displaying data from second DB table

Comment: Your json output is not a valid json try here jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

```
<?php

        $connection1=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",'json_data_db1');
        $connection2=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",'json_data_db2');
        // queries for 1st connection
        $query  = "select firstname,lastname,title,url from posts where id='6'";
        $sql=mysqli_query($connection1,$query) or die(mysql_error());  


        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
        $lastname=$row['lastname'];
        $title=$row['title'];
        $url=$row['url'];
        $result[0] = array("firstname" => $firstname,
              "lastname" => $lastname,
              "title" => $title,
              "image" =>$url );
        }

        // queries for 2nd connection 
        $query  = "select * from posts2 where id='6' limit 20";
        $sql=mysqli_query($connection2,$query);

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                $exp=$row['exp'];
                $des=$row['des'];
                $company=$row['company'];
                $location=$ow['location'];
                $result[1] = array("experience" => $exp,
                "designation" => $des,
                 "company" => $company,
                 "location" =>$location );    

            }

       $final_result['posts'] = array_merge($result[0],$result[1]);
        echo json_encode($final_result);

        mysqli_close($connection1);
        mysqli_close($connection2);
        ?>
```

so you will get the result like

```
{ "posts": { "firstname": "devika", "lastname": "v", "title": "Hyderabad", "image": "Chrysanthemum.jpg","experience": "software engineer", "designation": "Software Engineer", "company": "Topnottch", "location": "" }};
```

Then you will get two object on jquery use this

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
  console.log(value.firstname);
  console.log(value.company);

});
```

Comment: Here i given in javascript to display ,But its results undefined $.each(data.posts,function(key,value){
 var div_data ="<div><table><tr><td>"+data.firstname+"</td><td>"+data.experience+"</td></tr></table>"
 $(div_data).appendTo("#data_area");
});

Comment: @Devika514 not data.posts. try data.

Comment: @Devika514 the code has to  be  $.each(data,function(key,value){ var div_data ="<div><table><tr><td>"+value.firstname+"</td><td>"+value.experience+"</td></tr></‌​table>" $(div_data).appendTo("#data_area"); });

Comment: Yea.i tried with that.But its also showing undefined

Comment: what is your json response. please paste it here

Comment: Hey Its worked with "value" as prefix..Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
$connection1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", 'json_data_db1');
$connection2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", 'json_data_db2');
// queries for 1st connection
$query = "select id,firstname,lastname,title,url from posts where id='6'";
$sql = mysqli_query($connection1, $query) or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    // just save that with the id as key
    $data[$row['id']] = $row;
}

// queries for 2nd connection 
$query = "select * from posts2 where id='6' limit 20";
$sql   = mysqli_query($connection2, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    // use the same entry from above
    if (isset($data[$row['id']])) {
        $data[$row['id']]['exp'] = $row['exp'];
        $data[$row['id']]['des'] = $row['des'];
        $data[$row['id']]['company'] = $row['company'];
        $data[$row['id']]['location'] = $row['location'];
    }
}

// dont encode yourself, just use this
echo json_encode(array_values($data));

mysqli_close($connection1);
mysqli_close($connection2);
```